# How to change the title of the mail view

Tags: ios

I have an app that sends an email.  I noticed that when I set the subject, it also changes the title of the mail view like this:

[image]

The problem is that if the subject of the email is long, it is cut off in the window title; when the subject is translated, it's even worse, making the translation garbage. I need to change the view title to something meaningful, like "Export", not the Subject of the email..  Can this be done?  If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the standard, built-in Mail app's behavior. Even if you compose an email manually from the Mail app, you'll see that whatever you type in Subject will become the title in the navigation bar.

There is no reason why you should see garbage when the subject is translated though. You could post some code sample (even as another question) for help on this.

Comment: When the subject is longer than the space allocated to the title of the view, it has ellipsis (...) as the end... I understand that's the way it is created; what about sending the email "under the covers" where nothing is displayed... Can that be done in an iPhone/iPad app and still have the app accepted by the App Store?

Comment: Oh I see... So it's not really garbage, just truncated with ... appended to the end. I think users are well used to seeing this sort of truncation. After all they would see that themselves whenever they type an email with a longish subject line. At best you could try to keep the subject as concise and possible (e.g. just "Readings") or tell translators to shorten it if their translation truncates.

Comment: You're welcome! If you do want to send the email directly, I'm not aware of an existing iOS framework (but maybe there is one), however although it's not ideal you could always host your own web service to do the emailing and call it from your app.

Answer (score 0):

The subject field determines what the title of this view is. There is no way to change the title other than editing the Subject field.